# How to show PassCode View in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, passwords, uitableview

I have this layout in storyboard for my ipad app.
NavRootController--->LoginVC--->TabViewController(5 tabs)

I have added PassCodeVC that I would like to display modally in "ApplicationDidEnterForeground", and when code entered it goes to the view where the user was at last. I am not sure which Controller would present the PassCodeViewController?

Comment: You can have the controller as an orphan in the storyboard (or just in its own nib) and then have the app delegate create an instance of it and ask the root view controller to present it (you'll either need to wire an outlet to the app delegate for your root view controller like the old style, or just get the root view controller reference from the main window).

Comment: In the PassCodeVC, if the user enters thr correctCode, Where do I hook this up to to lead him to the last View he was on? Or, should I dismiss the modalView at that point?

Comment: Yeah, just dismiss it. That's why the app delegate is having the root view controller present it. It just obscures whatever else was going on, and when it gets dismissed, the user is in exactly the same place. If the data on the view behind may be sensitive, however, you should present the password view without animating so that it's just there as soon as the phone unlocks and nobody gets a chance to see what was behind it.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I guess at this point I've basically answered your question. I was hoping someone would come along and write it up with a code example or whatever :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rootView Controller presented the PassCodeView. I displayed the passcode View modally from ApplicationDidEnterForeground.